# API call bound with website form submission failed in Cypress

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to submit a form in a web application and noticed that its not updating values in the database. The issue is, API call related to the form submit failed with error NS_BINDING_REDIRECTED when its complete by cypress browser tab as follows.

[image]

The request body is empty in the failed API call.

[image]

When I'm trying in a different tab of the browser initiated by the Cypress, it was successful and the API call contained a body.

[image]

Also the API call error occurred, when I hold the automation in the form and manually enter the data and submit in the same browser tab initiated by the Cypress.

Cypress Code used to submit the form

```
cy.dbquery(SQL_ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT, product).then((SQL_ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT_RS) => {
        let activation_key = String(SQL_ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT_RS.rows[0]);
        cy.url().then((url) => {
            const current_url = new URL(url);
            const protocol = current_url.protocol;
            const host = current_url.hostname;
            const activation_url = `${protocol}//${host}/activate-account-creation?key=${activation_key}`;
            cy.log(`[SELF SERV] Activating MyAccount: ${activation_url}`)
            cy.visit(activation_url).then(() => {
                cy.url().should('include', '/complete-account-creation');
                cy.get('div').contains('Thank you for validating your email address.').then(($el) => {
                    expect($el).to.be.visible;
                })
            })
        })
    })

    cy.get('#title').select('Mr', { force: true })
    cy.get('#firstName').clear().type('Madhawa', { force: true })
    cy.get('#lastName').clear().type('Ratnayake', { force: true })
    cy.get('#telephoneNumber').clear().type('0713661579', { force: true })
    cy.get('#day').clear().type('27', { force: true })
    cy.get('#month').clear().type('05', { force: true })
    cy.get('#year').clear().type('1989', { force: true })

    cy.get('#postCode').clear().type('NN47YB', { force: true }).then(() => {
        cy.get('#findAddress').click().then(() => {
            cy.get('#dropDownListCompleteRegistration').select('Services', { force: true })
        })
    })
    cy.get('#activateForm').submit()
```